# How do I set the animated container without error when opening the picture?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

When I press the arrow button on the left using the animation container, I want it to slide down, but the picture is loaded before and it gives an error. How do I synchronize the picture with the container?

[image]

[image]

here I gave the animated container in the picture. To grow in the picture at the same time as the growth rate of the container, but it did not happen. I tried using the Animation control but didn't understand exactly how to use it in the Animation container.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import '../models/question_model.dart';
import 'package:date_format/date_format.dart';

class ActiveQuestion extends StatefulWidget {
  final Question question;
  ActiveQuestion({Key key, this.question}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ActiveQuestionState createState() => _ActiveQuestionState();
}
class _ActiveQuestionState extends State<ActiveQuestion> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  bool tapped = false;
  double _margin = 15;
  double _height = 120;
  Color _color = Colors.white;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
     duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(_margin),
      width: double.infinity,
      height: _height,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: _color,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black,width: 3.0)
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              if (!tapped)
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _height +=250;
                        tapped = tapped ? false : true;
                      });

                    },
                  ),
                ),
              if (tapped)
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _height -=250;
                        tapped = tapped ? false : true;
                      });

                    },
                  ),
                ),
              Flexible(
                flex: 4,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Flexible(child: Text(widget.question.title,style: GoogleFonts.rokkitt(fontSize: 20),)),

                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [

                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.comment),
                            Text(widget.question.answerCount.toString(),style: GoogleFonts.rokkitt(fontSize: 18),),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Text("@" + widget.question.name,style: GoogleFonts.rokkitt(fontSize: 18),),
                        Text('${formatDate(DateTime.parse(widget.question.time),[dd,'.',mm,".",yy," ",HH,":",nn])} ',style: GoogleFonts.rokkitt(fontSize: 18),),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          if(tapped)
            Divider(thickness: 1,),
          if (tapped)
          AnimatedContainer(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: _height,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
            child: SizedBox(
              child: Image(
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                image: NetworkImage(widget.question.questPath,),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by simply wrapping your Image (or SizedBox) in a [ClipRect](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipRect-class.html). The linked page includes an example showing how to define the alignment of the child. In your case, I imagine you'll want to align it to the top.